# Синхронизация константа и JSON базы

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, synchronized

Я хочу, чтобы данные в константе или объекте обновлялись, т.е. я меняю конфиги в JSON базе, скрипт схватывает и обновляет данные в константе или объекте. Пробовал `const` на `let` заменять, но это глупо и бесполезно. Я хочу обновлять данные константа или объекта из JSON базы не перезапуская скрипт. Скажу сразу с JSON базы на SQL и другие переходить желания нет.

```js
let configs = null
let addition = null
let realties = null
let estates = null

setInterval(() => {
   configs = require("./configs.json")
   addition = require("./addition.json")
   realties = addition.realties
   estates = addition.estates
 }, 6000)
```

Comment: а что такое JSON базы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Способ от пользователя DiD и Ghost мало чем помог, ибо у меня не работало. Я написал своё, вот пример:

````
const base = require("./base.json"); // ваш путь к JSON-файлу или базе
setInteval(()=>{
   const prebase = fs.readFileSync("./base.json"); // читаем файл JSON, здесь нам выдаст шифованный или двоичный код
   Object.assign(base, JSON.parse(prebase)) //JSON.parse переведет прочитанные данные в нормальный JSON, т.е. не двоичный, и перезапишет данные в объекте base на новые
   console.log('okay! синхронизация базы завершена!') // сообщение все успешно прошло
},15000) // обновляет данные каждые 15000 миллисекунд, т.е. 15 секунд```
````

Comment: долго работает в таком режиме?

Comment: Какой там приходит шифрованный двоичный код? в JSON-то файле? Кодировку указывать надо! Удивило, что `JSON.parse()` смог распарсить нодовский `Buffer`. По идее, так должно было не работать, но видимо, сработал `Buffer#toString()`

Answer (score 3):

Вам нужно следить за файлом с помощью [fs.watchFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watchfile_filename_options_listener)

Если что-то копирует конфиг к себе нужно оповистить тот код об изменениях

Можно сделать оповещение через [eventEmmiter класс](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html)

Answer (score 0):

Можно оставить `const`. Но тогда обновлять придется так:

```js
const configs = {} // не null, а {}

console.log(configs);

Object.assign(configs, {
  my: 'config',
  addition: '123'
});

console.log(configs);

Object.assign(configs, {
  my: 'config',
  config: 'my',
  addition: '123'
});

console.log(configs);
```

Обновления ФС, как уже написали, делаете с `fs.watchFile`, а чтение можно сделать и через `fs.readFile`, но не забыв распарсить `JSON.parse`:

```
const configs = require('./configs'); // первый раз можно и с require
// а все последующие разы require будет возвращать одно и тоже
// независимо от того, менялся конфиг или нет

fs.watchFile("./configs.json", ()=>{
   fs.readFile("./configs.json", "utf8", (file)=>{
      Object.assign(configs, JSON.parse(file));
   }
})
```

Comment: Перепроверил. Код рабочий. Ошибок нет.